# Statistical test for joint stationarity?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

Suppose I am given two time series, $x_t$ and $y_t$. I wish to determine if they are jointly stationary because I want to make a cross-correlation function and know that it's really a function only of the lag, i.e., that the correlation $\rho(x_t,y_s)$ depends only on $h = |t-s|$ and not on $t$ or $s$. I know how to test that $x_t$ is stationary and that $y_t$ is stationary, but I don't know a test for joint stationarity. Is there a statistical test for this? Can it be carried out in R?

Comment: Hi David: I don't know the whole literature but I think that it's generally more of an assumption than something that can be proven empirically. One necessary condition would be that both series are stationary so best to de-mean or use a transfer function to get rid of any properties that would imply non-stationary behavior of either series separately.

Comment: @mlofton Thanks. Yes, we did that and then the students were asking me how to check the remaining condition in the definition of joint stationarity. I did mention that later, once we have better modeling techniques, we can model each of the time series individually (e.g., with ARMA models or spectral models) and then only use the CCF on their residuals, where the condition is more likely to be satisfied. But I'm still hoping someone knows a test for checking this condition. I'm sure that's what my students want.

Comment: Thanks for context. I don't know of such a test but I guess it's possible that there may be one out there. A time series expert such as James Hamilton would probably know whether there is such a test.  I've asked him a few time series questions in the past and he's always been quite generous and responsive. Just a thought.